# ColSpan for Silverlight Datagrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a need to customize a Datagrid, for a TimeManagement system, using rowspawns.
My desired look is something like:

```
Customers| Projects  | Tasks  | Moanday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
         |           | Task 1 |   0     |   0     |    0      |    0     |   0    |
Customer1| Project 1 | Task 2 |   0     |   0     |    0      |    0     |   0    |
         |           | Task 3 |   0     |   0     |    0      |    0     |   0    |
```

Preferebly, i would like to be able to just give the DataGrid.ItemSource a List of Customers and it should work based on that.
My current Model is

```
    public class Customer
    {
       public string Name{get; set;}
       public List<Project> Projects{ get; set;}
    }
    public class Project
    {
       public string Name {get; set;}
       public List<Task> Tasks{ get; set; }
    }
    public class Task
    {
       public string Name { get; set;}
       public Week Week { get; set; }
    }
    public class Week 
    {
       public double Monday { get; set; }
       ...
    }
```

- I would like the Customer Cell to have a rowspan over all of its project rows.
- I would like the Project cell to have a rowspan over all of its task rows.
- And, most importantly, i need the user to be able to navigate around using the      arrowkeys on the keyboard.

My first attempt was to create new datagrids inside cells of another datagrid.
It seems a user is not able to navigate from one datagrid to another using the arrowkeys.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the "RowDetailsTemplate" in the DataGrid.  It's a section that can be expanded beneath a row.  Inside the RowDetailsTemplate you can add whatever you need, such as a grid or even a datagrid.    Set the RowDetailsVisibilityMode attribute to Visible, and it will always be shown.

Good luck.

--Matt